# Any way to use a TestSuite (instead a TestCase) with rostest?

Tags: python, rostest, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**UPDATE:** See rosticket [#423](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/423)

I am using rostest under rosbuild to create unittests with Python.

I understand how to create unittests and rostests, for instance, to create a TestsCase and call it from rostest.rosrun:

```
import unittest
class MyFirstTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # SetUp code
    
    def tearDown(self):
        # TearDown code

    def test_something(self):
        # some test code

    def test_more_stuff(self):
        # more test code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import rostest
    rostest.rosrun('my_package', 'test_my_first_test_case', MyFirstTestCase)
```

However, I you want to create more TestCases it is good idea to add them to a TestSuite. For instance something like this:

```
import unittest
class MyFirstTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # ...

class AnotherTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # SetUp code
    
    def tearDown(self):
        # TearDown code

    def test_another_thing(self):
        # some test code

    def test_yet_another_thing(self):
        # more test code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    def suite():
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(MyFirstTestCase('test_something'))
        suite.addTest(AnotherTestCase('test_another_thing'))
        return suite

    my_suite = suite()
    import rostest
    rostest.rosrun('my_package', 'test_my_first_test_suite', my_suite)
```

Note that the call to rostest.rosrun uses a unittest.TestSuite as argument rather than a unittest.TestCase.

But it seems that rostest.rosrun is not compatible with unittest.TestSuite, since after runing this code you would get a TypeError like the following:

> rostest.rosrun('my_package','test_my_first_test_case', my_suite)
> File
> "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostest/**init**.py",
> line 136, in rosrun
> suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test)
> File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py",
> line 50, in loadTestsFromTestCase
> if issubclass(testCaseClass, suite.TestSuite): TypeError:
> issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

After reading the documentation and looking for some examples I did not found any way to call a TestSuite from rostest.
Is it any way to properly create a TestSuite under rostest?

Some partial solution would be calling the different TestCases in different calls to rostest.rosrun like that:

```
rostest.rosrun('my_package', 'test_my_first_test_case', MyFirstTestCase)
rostest.rosrun('my_package', 'test_another_test_case', AnotherTestCase)
```

But, somehow, rostest only outputs the results for the second call to rostest.rosrun unless --text is passed ([see this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/48508/rostest-only-reports-one-test-case-result/)). This is not desirable since --text is more verbose and increases testing time.
Moreover, I believe using a TestSuite would be much more flexible than manully adding calls to rostest.rosrun.

**EDIT:** I edited the title to make the question clearer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122786/any-way-to-use-a-testsuite-(instead-a-testcase)-with-rostest?/) by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A small update on this in case people come here for an answer.
Rostests do work with TestSuite objects now.
[This issue](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/722) fixed the problem in ROS Indigo release. There is also a simple example on the github page.

What is missing is how to run tests that are part of a test case and not override `runTest` method of a `TestCase` object. And this is also more of a Python thing than ROS. Implementing the TestSuite like this solves the issue and allows you to run the test suite:

```
class SuiteTest(unittest.TestSuite):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(SuiteTest, self).__init__()
        self.loader = unittest.TestLoader()
        self.addTest(self.loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(CaseA))
        self.addTest(self.loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(CaseB))
```

Running the test as explained in the github link would be

```py
rostest.rosrun('test_rosbag', 'temp_tests', 'tmp.SuiteTest', sys.argv)
```

where `tmp` is the file name.

---

Originally posted by [Keivan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25583/keivan/) with karma: 16 on 2022-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2022-08-30**:
I marked your post as an answer, as it looks indeed [ros_comm#423](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/423) is addressed. And there's already wiki document that utilizes this development http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#Using_Test_Suites

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that (someone correct me if I'm wrong) the term `suite` may be used in `rostest` not as its specific usage in software testing context (as in `testsuite`) but as something more general, like composite or group of `TestCases`. And `unittest.TestSuite` isn't handled yet in rostest.

Thus it's worth opening an enhancement request on [its issue tracker](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues).

(As a workaround I usually put TestCase classes in separate `.py` files, which isn't that cumbersome if I have only several TestCases.)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2014-06-02**:
Thanks Isaac, I opened an issue [423](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/423)